# Datatables throws error when using the exact same code in different controllers and views

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

Ok, it's quite late here and I may be missing something stupidly obvious but as it stands the error I am receiving (below) makes absolutely no sense.

I currently have the below C# code in two separate controllers, fundamentally the results returned in one of the JsonResults will be different but for now I copied the code to rule out an underlying issue.

```
public JsonResult GetProducts(DataTableParameters param)
{
    var products = _productsRepository.GetAll().ToList();

    var totalRecords = products.Count();
    var filteredUsers = totalRecords;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
    {
        products =
            products.Where(w => w.ProductName.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
                w.Description.Contains(param.sSearch)).ToList();

        filteredUsers = products.Count();
    }

    var productList = products.Select(product => new[] { 
        Url.Action("Details", "ProductAdminstration", new {id = product.ProductId}),
        product.Description,
        product.Price.ToString(),
        string.Empty,

        product.ProductName,
        Url.Action("Edit", "ProductAdminstration", new { id = product.ProductId }),
        Url.Action("Delete", "ProductAdminstration", new { id = product.ProductId })
    });

        var parms = new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = totalRecords,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredUsers,
            aaData = productList
        };

        return Json(parms, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The above code works in the Index view of the `ProductAdminstration` controller, the datatables renders the data as anticipated using the below JQuery and obviously a table rendered in the HTML with the appropriate ID.

```
oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": "No results available",
    "sSearch": "Search",
    "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_",
    "sProcessing": "Processing" },
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetProducts", "ProductAdminstration")",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [ 
        //RENDER COLUMNS HERE 
    ]}).fnSetFilteringDelay(500);
```

However, if I copy the above code from ProductAdminstration (JQuery and JsonResult) to another controller (Ordering) and change sAjaxSource to point at the new controller the below error gets thrown:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: DataTables warning: table id=products - Invalid 
JSON response.
```

Baring in mind, the only thing I've changed is the controller name in sAjaxSource and if I change the controller name back to `ProductAdminstration` instead of `Ordering` everything works perfectly normal.

Both controllers require the user to be authenticated, however, I've removed my custom handler off the Ordering controller to rule out any issues. I've had a look around for the above error, and although there is a lot of information on the subject it doesn't seem to explain what is causing this problem when in one scenario it works perfectly fine, but in the other it doesn't.

Edit:

If it helps anyone, I cannot even type in the URL manually to get the JSON result from `http://localhost:50210/Ordering/GetProducts` (I'm not working with a live server yet so I cannot point you to a live URL). It renders the page then throws a hissy fit, instead of doing a download.

Comment: Can you try copying the JSON response from the erroring controller and running it through a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the JsonResult in the server logic is never hit. I've had breakpoints in the method since before the error began so I could test it as I went, the breakpoint is never reached in the erroring controller.

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to see what is being sent and received?  When ever I get into a situation like this I use Fiddler to see what is different.  Also, it is a great tool.

Comment: Fiddler reports everything with a status code of 200, including an event for `GET /Ordering/GetProducts?sEcho=1&iColumns=4&sColumns=%2C%2C ....`, but no noticeable problems. However, the controller method isn't being touched. The code is exactly the same across two controllers, the JQuery has only been modified with the new controller path, that's the only change which has been made. It doesn't make sense why the code will work if its not looking at the controller I am currently in.

Comment: Everything else being equal, the only difference you have mentioned is _" I've removed my custom handler off the Ordering controller"_. What happens if you remove it from `ProductAdminstration`?

Comment: It still works perfectly fine. I'm going to take another look at it tonight when I get home from work.

Comment: Did you look at the json result in Fiddler to see if it was ok?

Comment: Yep I looked at Fiddler, everything reports that status code of 200. It's picking up a request to the JSONResult but the method is never getting hit. As far as I can see, Fiddler isn't reporting any problems. I'm going to start the entire method from scratch tonight and see if I can resolve it that way.

Comment: Problem resolved, see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came back to the code tonight to try and resolve the error. The custom authorise attribute was removed from the controller and even left it on at times, I even checked the AuthoriseCore override I made to see if there was something preventing the request, however no matter what I did nothing would work.

Finally, as a last ditch effort I removed the entire controller, the views and any files associated with the controller. Added a new controller using a different name, set up a new view and the JQUERY required to run Data Tables and for some reason (unbeknownst to me why) everything started working as expected.

I hate not knowing why this issue was caused and what was causing it, however I am happy the problem has been resolved. The help and advice in the comments is appreciated.

**Edit**

So a few moments ago I found the cause of the issue whilst making some changes to the Route Config file. Leading back to a comment I made in the original question, it was stupidly obvious and the reason why removing the controller worked is because the original controller had 2 RouteConfigs under 2 separate names, whereas the new controller hadn't been set-up in RouteConfig at the time. Therefore, the controller was getting confused and had no idea which one to look at, meaning it threw a hissy fit and decided it didn't want to work.

Comment: Glad to hear it, sorry I wasn't more help.

Comment: Not a problem the help was appreciated. To be honest I just accidentally found the route cause of the issue a few seconds ago while modifying some code. I'm going to update the answer in a moment.